# portfolio weights and loop sequence in R

Tags: r, loops, portfolio

i am trying to get some combinations out of this code: specifically, i would like to have, for each level of activism, all the combinations in which i have one asset that gets all the overweight while all the other ones get equaly underweighted (so up: +activism[i]; down: -activism[i]/4)

the idea was to underweigh all the existing weights (1) and then bring up just the ones that need to be upped (2).

```
activism=c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5); 
length(activism);
weights=c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2); 
portfolio=matrix(nrow=20,ncol=5); 
for (i in 20) {
for (j in length(activism)){
for(k in length(weights)){
portfolio[i,k]=weights[k]- activism[j]/(length(weight)-1) 
}}}`
```

the code doesn't work for 2 reasons:
1) i get a completely different table just from part (1)
2) i don't know how to set up the "if" in part (2) although i tried to look up as many guides as possible.

I realize this might be a simple question but all other similar questions were in different languages (C/python, etc) and i am not that familiar with programming codes.

Comment: It's a bit technical. Could you simplify the problem further and give the desired output? Could you give the reference of the other program that performs what you want to do?

Comment: I would post an image (second best: http://postimg.org/image/tdp3gjpw9/). in green i have what i would like to obtain and in red on the left it's my current result.

Comment: `for (i in 1:20)`. same for inner loops.

Answer (score 0):

I not quite happy with the function but it seems to work. Feel free to improve. Beware that weights is assigned outside the function. The function work only if you start from equal weights. Things goes more messy else. 
Waiting for some improvements.

```
activism <- c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.5); 
weights <- c(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2); 
test <- function(vec,weight){
#signature vector,scalor-> matrix
#reassign weights
n <-  length(vec)
a <- vec[1]+weight 
b <- vec[-1]-(weight/(n-1))
tmp <-  c(a,b[-1])
results <-  a * diag(length(vec)) + (matrix(1,nrow=n,ncol=n) - diag(n))*b[1]
return (results)
}
lapply(activism,function(x)test(weights,x))
```